# gcloud ubuntu 14.04 tomcat 8 can't deploy sqlitesync.war

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, java-8, ubuntu-14.04, tomcat8

I'm working on the backend for a university app development project and have run into a solid brick wall. I'm a bit of a noob with this stuff.

I've been given access to a gcloud vm instance running ubuntu server 14.04 and have been attempting to setup [Sqlite-Sync](http://docs.sqlite-sync.com/#introduction) on tomcat 8. My team is attempting to build Xamarin app with an sqlite DB that will sync with a MySQL remote DB.

Initially I installed LAMP, phpMyAdmin and tomcat on the instance. I spent way to long attempting to access tomcat via ipv4 port 8080 as it only seemed to be listening on ipv6. Once I managed to fix that and deployed the SqliteSync.war I ended up with missing dependency issues, specifically glassfish and it's maven dependencies.

So now, having installed the alleged dependencies and remove and [reinstalled tomcat](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04) (due it refusing to listen to anything on any protocol). I now can't deploy sqlitesync.war (or the most recent version that the OG dev sent me). I've been told that tomcat can't overwrite old .war and the old versions need to be removed manually, yet they don't seem to exist on my instance. Error logs tell me:

```
java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/webapps/SqliteSync_307.war (Permission denied)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/webapps/SqliteSync_307.war (Permission denied)

18-May-2017 10:05:54.295 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: FAIL -    Deploy Upload Failed, Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/webapps/SqliteSync.war (Permission denied)
```

I'm seriously stuck and would appreciate any assistance. Do I burn the whole thing down and start again? Is it just some sort of permissions issue?

Comment: try https://askubuntu.com

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that too.